# Custom BeanELResolver using primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using the dynamic columns feature, provided by primefaces library. Because I also have nested properties (such as bean.city.address), I made a custom BeanElResolver to deal with that:

```
public class ExtendedBeanELResolver extends BeanELResolver {

@Override
public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property)
    throws NullPointerException, PropertyNotFoundException, ELException
{
    if (property == null || base == null || base instanceof ResourceBundle || base instanceof Map || base instanceof Collection) {
        return null;
    }

    String propertyString = property.toString();

    if (propertyString.contains(".")) {
        Object value = base;

        for (String propertyPart : propertyString.split("\\.")) {
            value = super.getValue(context, value, propertyPart);
        }

        return value;
    }
    else {
        return super.getValue(context, base, property);
    }
}
```

It works fine for the bean properties, but when the page is rendered I'm getting PropertyNotFound Exception for some image in primefaces, that is not a bean property:

```
 Servlet failed with an Exception -javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class      'org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler' does not have the property 'primefaces-   aristo:images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_c4c4c4_1x100.png'.
```

I think that is because I extended the BeanELResolver class and it somehow overrides the default ELResolver, that deals with all sorts of properties. I tried to make a CompositeELResolver class, to deal with other types of properties as well, but I can't figure out how. Any ideas?

Comment: i really do not understant what your purpose is. do you want yo use bean.city.address value/s on the page?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the values inside a <p:datatable> dynamically generating the columns.

Comment: primefaces dynamic columns component and dynamicly generatin columns are different. do you want to show/hide some columns depending on a condition? it is not needed that your class extend BeanELResolver in both cases.

Comment: I'm using the primefaces dynamic columns like in the showcase, only that by [column.property], I also have nested properties such as city.address, as I said. I simply want to display the values from the managed bean in the datatable. That's why I thought I should extend the BeanELResolver .